# How to make xAxis labels match the positions of bars Highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I made a drill down bar chart with highchart js library where the columns have different intervals.Because I want to make different size of bars, I used load and render function to change the size of the bars.

Now I wonder how to make the xAxis labels match the current position of each bar.Also my tooltip and data labels have the same problems as xAxis labels,I wonder how to solve this problem?

```js
// Create the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    events: {
      load: function() {

        this.series[0].data[0].graphic.attr({
          x: 10,
          width: 20
        });
        this.series[0].data[1].graphic.attr({
          x: 80,
          width: 40
        });
        this.series[0].data[2].graphic.attr({
          x: 150,
          width: 80
        });
      },
      render: function() {
        console.log(this.series[0].options._levelNumber)
        if (this.series[0].options._levelNumber == 0) {
          this.series[0].data[0].graphic.attr({
            x: 10,
            width: 20
          });
          this.series[0].data[1].graphic.attr({
            x: 80,
            width: 40
          });
          this.series[0].data[2].graphic.attr({
            x: 150,
            width: 80
          });
        }
      }
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Basic drilldown'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    title: {
      enabled: true,
      text: "Percentage Range"
    }
  },
  yAix: {
    title: {
      enabled: true,
      text: "Number of Schools"
    }
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      borderWidth: 0,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
      }
    }
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'Things',
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: [{
      name: '100-70%',
      y: 5,
      drilldown: '100-70%'
    }, {
      name: '70-30%',
      y: 2,
      drilldown: '70-30%'
    }, {
      name: '30-0%',
      y: 4,
      drilldown: '30-0%'
    }]
  }],
  drilldown: {
    series: [{
      id: '100-70%',
      data: [
        ['Cats', 4],
        ['Dogs', 2],
        ['Cows', 1],
        ['Sheep', 2],
        ['Pigs', 1]
      ]
    }, {
      id: '70-30%',
      data: [
        ['Apples', 4],
        ['Oranges', 2]
      ]
    }, {
      id: '30-0%',
      data: [
        ['Toyota', 4],
        ['Opel', 2],
        ['Volkswagen', 2]
      ]
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Divide your series into three individual series and set on each different `pointPadding` property. Also, disable `grouping`. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/a1at7sgb/.

Comment: @d_paul Hello. I wonder how to shorten the blank distance between these bars after changing their pointPadding. I tried pointWidth too, but they cannot be distributed horizontally.

Comment: You can try to use pointPlacement property (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.pointPlacement). Example: https://jsfiddle.net/7vn1nqm0/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using event to change the width of the columns,you can define with of each data series either using `pointPadding` or `pointWidth` . This display the chart properly

Series will be

```
  series: [{
    name: 'Things',
    colorByPoint: true,
    pointPadding: 0,
   // pointWidth:80, you can use this as well
    data: [{
      name: '100-70%',
      y: 5,
      drilldown: '100-70%',
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Things',
    colorByPoint: true,
    pointPadding: 0.2,
    // pointWidth:100, you can use this as well
    data: [{
      name: '70-30%',
      y: 2,
      drilldown: '70-30%'
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Things',
    colorByPoint: true,
    pointPadding: 0.3,
    // pointWidth:120, you can use this as well
    data: [{
      name: '30-0%',
      y: 4,
      drilldown: '30-0%'
    }]
  }],
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/0fw1ot58/) demonstration

Comment: Hello. pointPadding works very well. But I wonder how to minimize the distance between the bars. I tried pointWidth too, some of the bars are hiding behind other bar. Is it possible to customize the interval so I can make the bars keep closer to each other.

Answer (score 0):

What you do in `load` and `render` functions?
If delete it, looks like everything is ok:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Basic drilldown'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        title:{
        enabled:true,
        text: "Percentage Range"
        }
    },
        yAix:{
    title:{
        enabled:true,
        text: "Number of Schools"
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Things',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: '100-70%',
            y: 5,
            drilldown: '100-70%'
        }, {
            name: '70-30%',
            y: 2,
            drilldown: '70-30%'
        }, {
            name: '30-0%',
            y: 4,
            drilldown: '30-0%'
        }]
    }],
    drilldown: {
        series: [{
            id: '100-70%',
            data: [
                ['Cats', 4],
                ['Dogs', 2],
                ['Cows', 1],
                ['Sheep', 2],
                ['Pigs', 1]
            ]
        }, {
            id: '70-30%',
            data: [
                ['Apples', 4],
                ['Oranges', 2]
            ]
        }, {
            id: '30-0%',
            data: [
                ['Toyota', 4],
                ['Opel', 2],
                ['Volkswagen', 2]
            ]
        }]
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w13u9hk9/1/

Comment: Cause I want to make different width of bars, so I use load and render function to get different widths. But I want other labels match my current positions of bars, I don't know how to do it.